# When is a "Try" method preferred over a "null" result?

Tags: .net, design-patterns

In the .NET Framework (around the advent of generics), the `Try[method]` pattern emerged to help deal with the situation where an operation needed to indicate it failed to complete successfully without throwing an exception.

In situations where failure is considered normal (such as parsing) and not exceptional, this is obviously a desirable pattern to follow.

However, if a method can return `null` to indicate it failed to get a value successfully (such as in the case of a `Find` method), is this considered more correct than a `TryFind` method which clearly indicates success or failure with a return value? Is there any precedent set by the .NET Framework to this pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the TryX pattern pre-dates `Nullable<T>` types, which were added in .NET 2.0. `Nullable<T>` solved the problem of value types and the potential discrepancies between whether the default type value was valid/invalid. However, even with these additions, I do believe the TryX pattern still holds value.

The two major benefits of the TryX pattern are:

- No ambiguity of return value.
- Safety from exceptions.

`Nullable<T>` types remove ambiguity but do not provide exception safety.

I don't believe there is a concrete precedence set, but if your method needs to guarantee these, then I would use the TryX pattern.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with a `null` return type is that you need to check for it - this may not be obvious and is easy to forget.

Using a `Try*` type method makes the flow much clearer.

Having said that, the [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) exists exactly because of the issues with returning a null - it allows you to use a "null" object for your type, a valid object that represent a neutral value.

Comment: Haven't seen the Null Object pattern referenced for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

1. Normal value types don't support `null`. And while there are nullable value types, generics don't support a construct like: Return `T?` if `T` is a value type, and `T` if it's a reference type.
2. On types supporting `null`, `null` is a valid value. Users might want to distinguish between missing entries, and entries that are `null`.

On the other hand it would be possible to define an `Option<T>` struct that is returned. Such a type would also be useful in other places(for example optional parameters).

---

Interestingly the non generic `HashTable` class return `null` in its indexer when the element isn't present:

> The value associated with the specified key. If the specified key is not found, attempting to get it returns null, and attempting to set it creates a new element using the specified key.
>
> To distinguish between null that is returned because the specified key is not found and null that is returned because the value of the specified key is null, use the Contains method or the ContainsKey method to determine if the key exists in the list.

Comment: This: "null is a valid value. Users might want to distinguish between missing entries, and entries that are null."  +1

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few TryParse methods returns Values and not objects meaning they can't return null. Sure with the introduction of Nullable they could be written to return null but null is defined as "no information". In the case of an exception/error that's not semantically correct. Returning true upon succes and false upon failure clearly represent this information. 
As commented below this also inline with the design of the TryParse method in the .NET framework. They were introduced at the same time as Nullable
You also avoid some one using the return value with out checking for null which is easier to do by mistake than to forget to check the result of a TrySomthing method

Comment: The `TryParse` methods were introduced in Framework 2.0, which is the same version `Nullable<T>` was introduced. The concept existed, but the designers decided to take a different approach.

Comment: @ProgrammingHero kind of my point :) which I've now tried to make a little clearer thanks for the comment (The TryParse kind of method is older than the introduction of the methods in .NET)

Answer (score 0):

exceptions should never be used for flow-control or results of a method. of course, there are always exceptions to this rule.  this is part of the reason to use `TryParse` over `Try`

Comment: I can't see OP suggesting to use exceptions as flow control (rather the opposite actually)

Answer (score 0):

One reason is when you are returning a struct which cannot be `null`, ie. `double.TryParse()`.

Comment: but that could be rewritten to return Nullable<double> I don't believe it should though

Comment: First of all, this method was implemented *before* `Nullable<T>` was introduced. Also, the common pattern in BLC is for `Parse` is to throw when the parsing fails. `TryParse` methods return `boolean` and use `out` parameter to return the actual value when parsing succeeds.

Comment: yes double.TryParse (as oppossed to int.TryParse) was introduced prior to Nullable<T> but as I read OP he's not asking retrosepctively he's asking in regards to he's current work so a retrospective argument which does not hold for new development doesn't help alot imho

Answer (score 0):

For methods returning class types, I would prefer a `TryGetFnord()` method which returns null on failure to be preferable to one which returns `bool` and stores its result in a `ref` parameter.  Among other things, one can include the the former style in a covariant interface, whereas one cannot do so with the latter style.  I would suggest keeping the "Try" in the name, however, to indicate that the method could fail.

Another approach to consider would be something like: `dataType TryGetFnord(ref TryGetFnordResult result)`, where `TryGetFnordResult` could be a value type or immutable class type which indicates whether the operation succeeded.  This would preserve the covariance-related advantages while allowing more useful information to be returned than just a pass-fail.  In case the operation fails, it should probably return the default value for its type, but the caller should check for failure using the `result` parameter.